# How come $(\mathbb{R},\cdot)$ does not form a group?

Tags: group-theory

This is probably a very obvious question but I've only just started learning group theory today. Is the reason that $(\mathbb{R},\cdot)$ does not form a group, because its operation is multiplication? Then wouldn't this mean that a group's operation can never be multiplication?

Comment: What would be the inverse of $0$ in $(\Bbb R, \times)$? What happens if you consider instead $(\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}, \times)$?

Comment: I understand now that it can't be a group because 0 has no inverse, but wouldn't that mean that for any set it couldn't be multiplication?

Comment: $(\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}, \times)$ is a group, as well as $\{\pm 1\}$, endowed with the usual multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly as Watson says. Remember that a group must have:

1. An identity element. What is the identity in this case? You need some element $e \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $e \cdot \lambda = \lambda$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. This is equivalent to $(e - 1) \cdot \lambda = 0$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, which has a unique solution.
2. Given the identity element, every element (**Edit**: including it) has an inverse according to the group operation. That is, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there is a *unique* element $y$ such that $x \cdot y = e = y \cdot x$. For the most part, this is fine! However, thing about what you chose as an identity element in part 1. Is it possible that there is a *unique real number* $y$ such that $0 = 0 \cdot y = e$? Can these two properties ever be consistent?